# Actionbar has extra view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout

I have an actionbar, and there is something on the left side that I cannot remove or find.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

I made the background of the actionbar white to see the difference.

Here's the code for the actionbar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

mCustomAB = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.LEFT| Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomAB, lp);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
```

And here's the whole layout of the actionbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/drawer_right"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_alerts" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/alert_red"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/alert_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/alert_dimen"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drawer_right"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/drawer_right"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_alert_red" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/alert_red"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/alert_red"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/other_options"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dropdown" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SM MOON"
            android:textColor="@color/Theme"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

By the way, the main activity where this is put is a Drawer Layout. Not sure if it has any effect on it. I also tried putting a different bg color for the main layout, but nothing happened.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `Tip`: The LinearLayout at the end is completely **useless**.

Comment: `Tip`: `fill_parent` is **deprecated**. use `match_parent`, instead.

Answer (score 2):

it's the new Android `ToolBar`. Add

```
<style name="AppThemeToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item tools:ignore="NewApi" name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

to your style in order to remove the extra padding

Answer (score 0):

Try below code , it may helps you

```
LayoutInflater m_inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ActionBar m_actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        View m_viewActionBar = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_title_layout, null);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams m_params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
        TextView m_tvTitle = (TextView) m_viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.cal_tvActionbarTitle);
        m_tvTitle.setText(p_title);
        m_actionBar.setCustomView(m_viewActionBar, m_params);
        m_actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        m_actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        m_actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        m_actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

This is my custom actionbar layout file , you can change it according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cal_tvActionbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

code for Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_bg</item>
        <item name="background">@color/actionbar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_backarrow</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_backarrow</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```